# Can Hip-Hop/music trend be estimated?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, data

How can I determine how an "evolutionary" music album affects the development of its genre? Only two perspectives I can come up with: 1. The effect on the number of songs before and after(effect on popularity); 2. The effect on structures or applications of new instruments.
I have watched several videos doing this, and they use machines learnings(i am not sure).
Any ideas?

Currently, my plan is to discover the pattern of 808s drums in hip-hop music which is now widely used. I wish to find out how the timbre and popularity of 808s drums are different from the 1980s, and that how I consider the trend is. I am currently gathering 808s classic songs from Spotify and arraying them by release date

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Currently the question is too vague: how do you define a trend formally? Is there any labelled data that could be used, whether about type or song or instruments?

Comment: Hi, currently my plan is to discover the pattern of 808s drums in hip-hop music which is now widely used. I wish to find out how the timbre and popularity of 808s drums are different from the 1980s, and that how I consider the trend is. I am currently gathering 808s classic songs from Spotify and arraying them by release date.